# Hub disconnect from MacBook Pro 2018 Touch Bar

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I have a problem with my MBP 2018 Touch Bar.
Today I unplugged two hubs (with ethernet cable, HDMI, SD card reader and 4 USB ports)... and after this, when I plugged again the device the computer doesn't detect it, and I lost my other screen, keyboard, wacom, etc. Basically my workstation has been fall out

I tried to restart de SMC and PRAM. I reinstalled the OS too (Catalina 10.15.7)

The hubs are this:
https://cutt.ly/ugjYdwg

I need to finish a work for a costumer tomorrow...

Please! Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, The device is connected the power supply ;-)

Comment: Did you unplug while they were connected to the MBP while it was running, or after you had shut down?

Comment: While it was running. Please tell me that is not a computer hardware failure... :(

Answer (score -1):

I bought another hub and an Apple device, and now is working.

Comment: Without stating the manufacturer and model numbers of the hubs you had originally, and what "another hub" is, and what you mean by "Apple device," this answer is not useful.